# How do I add a custom key to mysql information_schema.COLUMNS

Tags: php, mysql

Im using this mysql statement `SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$dbck' AND TABLE_NAME = '$tbck' AND COLUMN_NAME = '$field_param'"`. How can I add a custom key to the mysql information_schema.columns to look like this?

```
    {
        "Field": "id",
        "Type": "mediumint(5) unsigned",
        "Null": "NO",
        "Key": "PRI",
        "Default": null,
        "Extra": "auto_increment",
        ***"CUSTOM_KEY": "custom_value"***
    }
```

Comment: [Cannot be done](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-information-schema.html#faq-mysql-can-modify-information-schema)

Comment: `@Slava` was able to provide a working solution.

Comment: Yes, as a work-around, which is absolutely fine, but is not a direct modification to information schema, as the question asked. If the solution was helpful, then kindly consider [accepting slava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). I'm up-voting for the work-around idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and fill your own table in your own database like :

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOM_COLUMNS_DATA (
  `TABLE_CATALOG` varchar(512) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TABLE_SCHEMA` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TABLE_NAME` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `COLUMN_NAME` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CUSTOM_KEY` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
);
```

and retrieve data using `JOIN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
JOIN mydb.CUSTOM_COLUMNS_DATA USING(`TABLE_CATALOG`, `TABLE_SCHEMA`, `TABLE_NAME`, `COLUMN_NAME`)
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$dbck' AND TABLE_NAME = '$tbck' AND COLUMN_NAME = '$field_param'"
```

Comment: Beautiful, great thinking.  This worked like a charm!  In fact I created as a `VIEW`.